# Can AWS ECS task definition YAML configs be extended?

Tags: amazon-web-services, yaml, amazon-ecs

Is it possible to import/extend an AWS ECS task definition in YAML?  For example, assume I have the following task definition in *ecs-task-django.yml*:

```
family: 'myproject-django'
executionRoleArn: 'arn:aws:iam::1234567890:role/ecsTaskExecutionRole'
networkMode: 'awsvpc'
requiresCompatibilities:
- FARGATE
cpu: '2048'
memory: '4096'

containerDefinitions:
- name: 'django'
  image: '1234567890.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/myproject/django'
  portMappings:
  - containerPort: 5000
    hostPort: 5000
    protocol: tcp
  command:
  - '/start'
  environment:
  - name: 'SOME_VAR'
    value: 'value1'
  - name: 'SOME_OTHER_VAR'
    value: 'value2'
```

I would like to create a second task definition for a scheduled service that runs using the same image, imports and extends the above config, but does not repeat what I have already defined above.  Pseudo-code would be something like *ecs-task-dothing.yml*:

```
# import ecs-task-django.yml

containerDefinitions:
- name: 'dothing'
  command:
  - 'python manage.py dothing'
  environment:
  - name: 'SOME_VAR'
    value: 'value2'
```

Is this possible, or do I have to basically repeat all the first task definitions and have two instances of those same values (not very DRY)?

Comment: Off course it's possible, but you have to do it yourself. Aws will not merge these files for you